# Load more button with javascript xml data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html-table

Im trying to limit table to show 10 rows once the xml data is loaded into the table and then have a load more button to show any more table rows after, but i cant seem to get it working?.

HTML

```
<table id="demo"></table>
```

JS

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/data.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table="<thead class=\"design1\"><tr><th>Data 1</th><th>Data 2</th><th>Headquarters</th><th>Data 3</th><th>Data 4:</th></tr></thead><tbody id='myTable'>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROOT");

    for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td><a target='_blank' href='"+ x[i].getElementsByTagName("site")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +"'>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</a></td><td>"  + x[i].getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>"  + x[i].getElementsByTagName("data1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("phone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td class='hidden'>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("country")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><td class='hidden'>" + x[i].getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +  "</td></tr>";
    }
   table += "</tbody>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Xml sample:
https://sendeyo.com/en/d7929496f2
(Could not add anymore code)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data.xml? Hard to reproduce without it.

Comment: Hi, i have added a link to download the xml sample - https://sendeyo.com/en/d7929496f2